# How to differentiate between exploratory and explanatory research?

Tags: research-process, research-topic, case-study

The way I gather, a explorative study is merely trying to identify certain concepts, whereas a explanatory study is trying to explain a A causes B relationship.

Especially with regard to case study research, Yin (book on case studies, 2014), mentions the following:

> 'For instance, many descriptive case studies deal with the “how” of a situation, whereas many explanatory case studies deal with the “why” of situations.'

But the way I see it, questions with regard to a 'how' situation are often explanatory in nature:

*How does using an umbrella influence your sogginess?* 
*How does e-commerce influence internationalisation process?* 
*How does smoking influence heart disease?*

Are these questions not explanatory in nature?

Comment: Are you conflating "exploratory" with "descriptive"? I think that the meaning of "descriptive" is much closer to "explanatory". I think there may be three concepts here, not two.

Comment: What do you mean "how to differentiate"? What will you do with the answer?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and give "We need both exploratory and confirmatory" by John Tukey a read. It begins with "We often forget how science and engineering function."

Comment: It is not about the research questions, it is about the methods and the design. Also, the terms exploratory and explanatory may have slightly different connotations across different fields.